# Python: looking for a substring within a series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, substring, list-comprehension

I'm trying to identify all the elements within a pandas Series (descriptions_list) that contains a the substring 'energy'. I've been trying to write a list comprehension in the following way:

```
descriptions_list 
energy = 'energy'

[i for i, j in enumerate(descriptions_list) if 'energy' in j]
```

Even though this works when working with short series objects (or just only analysing descriptions_lists from 0:4*10**4), for longer series I constantly get the following error: "argument of type 'int' is not iterable". It also works for any series length when removing the `$`if 'energy' in j`$` condition or when setting a very simple conditions such as `$`if 'a' in 'ba' `$`.

Why does it work for short ones only and how can I make it work for longer series?

Comment: OK, does `descriptions_list.str.contains('energy', na=False)` work?

Comment: It does, but I want to retrieve the indices of the ones which, in this case, hold true.

Comment: Try `descriptions_list.index[descriptions_list.str.contains('energy', na=False)]`

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks a lot! Could you explain me why my initial code does not work though?

Comment: Can you try with the following: [i for i, j in enumerate(descriptions_list) if 'energy' in str(j)] ?

Comment: It's probably because you have NaNs or mixed data, for whatever reason.